# Unable to override lagom kafka parameters

Tags: apache-kafka, lagom

I created a normal java project and put all dependencies of lagom kafka client on classpath , then in source folder i put the application.conf

Content of application.conf

```
lagom.broker.kafka {
  service-name = ""

  brokers = "127.0.0.1:9092"

}
```

while running the application service-name = "" should be used (so that my broker path could be used, rather than discovering), but it was not working

while debugging i found that in KafkaConfig class service-name comes out to be "kafka_native".

I found that while creating KafkaConfig , conf object which is coming dosen't have my application.conf in its origin

After this i tried overriding them using vm parameters like this:

```
-Dlagom.broker.kafka.service-name=""
-Dlagom.broker.kafka.brokers="127.0.0.1:9092"
-Dakka.kafka.consumer.kafka-clients.auto.offset.reset="earliest"
```

and it worked.

Can somebody explain why overriding in application conf not working

This is how i am subscribing to topic

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

import com.ameyo.ticketing.ticket.api.TicketingService;
import com.ameyo.ticketing.ticket.api.events.TicketEvent;
import com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.api.broker.Topic;
import com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.client.integration.LagomClientFactory;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

import akka.Done;
import akka.stream.javadsl.Flow;

/**
 *
 */

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String brokers = ConfigFactory.load().getString("lagom.broker.kafka.brokers");
        System.out.println("Initial Value for Brokers " + brokers);
        LagomClientFactory clientFactory = LagomClientFactory.create("legacy-system", Main.class.getClassLoader());
        TicketingService ticketTingService = clientFactory.createClient(TicketingService.class,
                URI.create("http://localhost:11000"));

        Topic<TicketEvent> ticketEvents = ticketTingService.ticketEvents();

        ticketEvents.subscribe().withGroupId("nya13").atLeastOnce(Flow.<TicketEvent> create().mapAsync(1, e -> {
            System.out.println("kuch to aaya");
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Done.getInstance());
        }));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000000000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your application.conf is not on the right place. Where did you put it? And btw, what do you mean by "normal java project"? Is this not a Lagom project and you are only bringing the Lagom Kafka API?

Comment: @Renato yes it is not a lagom project, it is a legacy system , i am using  LagomClientFactory to create the service stub , and application.conf is on the right place because if i do not put that file than java application dosen't saying that application.conf not found . also i am updating question on how i am subscribing so you will have a better idea

Comment: At first I would say, the application.conf is not available on the classloader being used. You can quickly check it on doing the following: 
Config conf = ConfigFactory.load(); config.getString("lagom.broker.kafka.brokers").

Comment: @Renato i tried with config.getString("lagom.broker.kafka.brokers") and it is giving the correct string as "127.0.0.1:9092" but still the KafkaConfig is getting brokers value as "localhost:9092" , then also i tried changing the ClassLoader, initially i was using the LagomClientFactory class loader than i changed this to Main class ClassLoader , still the issue persisted , i am using lagom 1.3.10

Comment: @Renato after putting configuration like this: akka{
 lagom.broker.kafka {
   service-name = ""
   brokers = "127.0.0.1:9092" 
 }
 lagom.broker.defaults.kafka { 
   brokers = "127.0.0.1:9092"
 }

}   ----- My issue got resolved , i reached to this conclusion as while creating Actor System in LagomClientFactory code is : ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("lagom-client", configuration.underlying().getConfig("akka"),
                classLoader);   --------- which is taking config only from akka, ---------- Is this the desired behaviour , as in documentation it is not given

Comment: @Renato , please suggest , should i close this one , raise a bug on github as well

Comment: yes, a github issue is the best approach. We can discuss what to do and how to fix it there. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change configuration to

```
akka{ 
    lagom.broker.kafka { 
        service-name = "" 
        brokers = "127.0.0.1:9092" 
    }
}
```

and it worked